# Visual studio project user security levels

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio, can I somehow restrict which files that can be seen by which user.

Eg. in a win forms application I can set my connectionStrings to the database in the properties file->settings. I would want someone to be able to work in the project but that he want be able to open the project file to eg see my connectionStrings?

Is this possible? Or what is the usual approach?

Comment: Why? If you can't access a file or setting you can't build or run your application. In a WinForms application just *don't* use password authentication, use Windows Authentication. Or use an account with restricted priviledges - definitely not `sa` or `root` or whatever

Comment: I would suggest the solution is via your configuration controls system, having triggers or plugins that restrict some user from some files or directories, or that require additional "management" approval before the files can be added to the "approved" areas of the project.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really possible without a great deal of work. The usual way to deal with this is to **not check those files in in the first place**.

What you do is check in template files, with safe defaults, or with placeholder values.

Then, when a new developer checks out the project, they copy (e.g.) `Web.config.template` to `Web.config` and edit it for their machine.

Configure your source control so that the file can't be easily added, and you should be fine.

*Alternatively, answer this question: why is it bad if another developer sees **your** connection strings?*

Comment: "Why is it bad if another developer sees your connection strings?" On some projects, only a few team members have direct access to the production systems.  That can reduce mistakes, since theoretically you only give access to your most-capable/most-careful/most-trusted people.  It also limits the damage a disgruntled employee can do, especially on short notice.  The trade-off is if there's a problem in production, you've got a smaller pool of people that can respond to it.

Comment: And those connection strings shouldn't be in source control (at least, not in the developers' repo). My question was: "why is it bad if another developer sees *your* connection strings?"

Comment: What I'm getting at is this: why are you still using connection strings that require plaintext usernames and passwords? It's 2017, use Kerberos or similar.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't restrict file visibility in Visual Studio (at least not in any way useful for your case).  A Visual Studio project is basically just a catalog of other files that should be displayed in the IDE and/or included in the build.  The sensitive information that you're worried about is actually stored in those other files (such as app.config for a desktop .NET application or web.config for an ASP.NET project).  Even if Visual Studio were willing to hide the files in the IDE, a malicious user could still open then using another text editor.

The way this is normally handled is that you don't include the sensitive data in your repository (nor in any code that you share other ways).  You only fill in the real passwords when you deploy your code.  You have the user type in the password when they run the application (if it's a client-side application) or you have a sysadmin or automated deployment tool add it to the config file on the production system if it's a web application.